# Google OAuth1 to OAuth2 migration - displays consent screen again

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I followed OAuth1 to OAuth2 migration documentation and was able to get new refresh_token and access_tokens.

The issue is, Google displays approval screen again and list all the scopes. The whole point of migrating the credentials is that user should not see the approval screen.

Here is my POST request for migration:

> POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
>   Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_consumer_key=[CONSUMER
>   KEY]",oauth_nonce="2c06a5da90ec4a62b737bdfb3922d675",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1411677478",oauth_token="[OAUTH
>   TOKEN]",oauth_signature="oL%2b2JdOBCKcND8cSHSmHQMRN5NI%3d"
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Host:
>   accounts.google.com Content-Length: 194 Expect: 100-continue
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   grant_type=urn%3aietf%3aparams%3aoauth%3agrant-type%3amigration%3aoauth1&client_id=&client_secret=[GENERATED
>   SIGNATURE]

Further more, if I check https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1 page to see which application I have given access to, I see my new application there, with all the scopes that older application had.

I also made sure that I don't include **approval_prompt=force**

Any thoughts? Am I wrong in assuming that the user will not see the approval screen after migration?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the point of migrating the credentials is that the user should not see the approval screen. But if you added any new scopes, maybe to use some APIs, most of them require the user to grant permission and therefore a approval screen will be displayed again.

Comment: In that case, it should only show approval screen for new scopes only. I did not add any new scope. Also, I do see the scopes getting transferred over (from Google's permissions page), but it still displays the approval screen.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify the steps and when does a user see the approval page? What scopes do your OAuth2 tokens have after the migration?

The migration is for a OAuth1 token that you have stored on your backend. With migration step you convert these to OAuth2 refresh token. You can start using these to make calls to Google APIs without a user showing up on your site.

Depending on how you got these OAuth1 tokens, you need to change that mechanism to start getting OAuth2 tokens. In general you want to do this only for the users you don't have a refresh token already stored as there is no point getting a new refresh token (if you do, they may see an approval screen).